# How to getting multiple tables in json from sql to android

Tags: java, php, android, sql, json

i try to get multiple table from json, i have two tables ( hotline and other ) , i can get data from hotline table, but cannot get from other table
in my php (json):

```
{"hotline":[{"id":"2","name_hotline":"Tourist Police","phone_hotline":"192"},{"id":"6","name_hotline":"Water","phone_hotline":"1199"}]}{"other":[{"id":"1","name_other":"Lao National Tourism Administration","phone_other":"+85621212248 ","latitude_other":"0","pic_other":"","longtitude_other":"0"},{"id":"2","name_other":"Tourism Police Department","phone_other":"+85621251128 ","latitude_other":"0","pic_other":"","longtitude_other":"0"}]}
```

MainActivity.java :

```
InputStream objInputStream = null;
    String strJSON = "";

    try {

        HttpClient objHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost objHttpPost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.102/emergencycall/php_get_data.php");
        HttpResponse objHttpResponse = objHttpClient.execute(objHttpPost);
        HttpEntity objHttpEntity = objHttpResponse.getEntity();
        objInputStream = objHttpEntity.getContent();

        Log.d("Emergency", "Connected HTTP Success !");


    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("Emergency", "Error Connect to : " + e.toString());
    }


    try {

        BufferedReader objBufferesReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(objInputStream, "UTF-8"));
        StringBuilder objStrBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String strLine = null;

        while ((strLine = objBufferesReader.readLine()) != null) {
            objStrBuilder.append(strLine);
        }

        objInputStream.close();
        strJSON = objStrBuilder.toString();

        Log.d("Emergency", "Connected JSON Success !");



    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("Emergency","Error Convert To JSON :" + e.toString() );
    }


    try {

        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(strJSON);
        JSONArray objJSONArray = object.getJSONArray("hotline");
        JSONArray objJSONAraay2 = object.getJSONArray("other");

        for (int i = 0; i < objJSONArray.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject objJSONObject = objJSONArray.getJSONObject(i);
            strNameHotlineMySQL = objJSONObject.getString("name_hotline");
            strPhoneHotlineMySQL = objJSONObject.getString("phone_hotline");

        }

        for (int j = 0; j < objJSONAraay2.length(); j++) {

            JSONObject objJSONObject1 = objJSONAraay2.getJSONObject(j);
            strNameHospitalMySQL = objJSONObject1.getString("name_other");
            strPhoneHospitalMySQL = objJSONObject1.getString("phone_other");

            long insertID4 = objHotlineTable.addDataFromSQLiteHospital(strNameHospitalMySQL, strPhoneHospitalMySQL, strPicHospitalMySQL);

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("Emergency","Error syncdata to SQLite :" + e.toString() );
    }
```

and i get an error in Logcat:

: Error syncdata to SQLite :org.json.JSONException: No value for other

Answer (score 0):

Your json data format is not correct. Json data format should be like this:

```
 {
   "hotline":[
      {
         "id":"2",
         "name_hotline":"Tourist Police",
         "phone_hotline":"192"
      },
      {
         "id":"6",
         "name_hotline":"Water",
         "phone_hotline":"1199"
      }
   ],
   "other":[
      {
         "id":"1",
         "name_other":"Lao National Tourism Administration",
         "phone_other":"+85621212248 ",
         "latitude_other":"0",
         "pic_other":"",
         "longtitude_other":"0"
      },
      {
         "id":"2",
         "name_other":"Tourism Police Department",
         "phone_other":"+85621251128 ",
         "latitude_other":"0",
         "pic_other":"",
         "longtitude_other":"0"
      }
   ]
}
```

And than,
    You can use "[Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/)" and "gson" for http request and object mapping.